# I need to delete a node in a linked list, how do I find the node that comes BEFORE it so I can rearrange the list?

Tags: java, list, linked-list

It's for a school assignment. I have to use a search method that returns the node that I search for or the one right before it if it doesn't exist. Obviously if I want to delete a node it'll return that one node and I won't be able to find the one that comes before it. Here's the code for the search method:

```
private myNode search(myEntry searchEntry)
{
  myNode ref = first;
  myNode pre = null;

  while(ref != null)
  {
     if(searchEntry.compareTo(ref.data) < 0)
        break;
     pre = ref;
     ref = ref.link;
  }
  return pre;
}
```

first is the first node, ref is the pointer, pre is the node preceding the pointer.
Maybe I'll use a doubly-linked list if it doesn't require me to rewrite things too much but if there's a simple way to find the predecessor of the node I'm trying to delete using this search method then I'd like to know. I'm not supposed to be using doubly-linked lists at all.

Comment: What do you mean "the one right before it if it doesn't exist"? If the node doesn't exist then there is no "the one right before it", right? There's nothing to be "before"!

Comment: You really need to improve this question. As it is, it makes little sense.

Comment: That's kind of why I posted the code for it.

Comment: How come your search returns the one before it if it doesnt exist? Seems very confusing for anyone using the method. Really it should return null or throw an checked exception if the node does not exist. Otherwise, how do you know what is returned is the found node or the one before it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with your search method. You have to implement a distinct search method that return the predecessor of the node and then delete it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to delete ref, than you return pre. To delete ref, you can write something like

```
pre = list.search(entry); //find the prescending node
ref = pre.link;           //get the node you want to delete
pre.link = ref.link;      //reassign link
ref.delete();             //delete node
```

Comment: then you need to remember the node, prescending to pre and return it. Do it in a similar way as you found pre (just add one more local variable). You don't need to return pre in you method. But you need to ensure that pre is not the first node, you need to analyse this case separately

Comment: @Raphaël: I doubt that you really want to delete 'pre'. It seems more likely that you'll want to **change** some piece of data in the node pointed to by 'pre'.  (Also, you'll have to deal with the special case when 'first' points to the thing you want to delete.)